# Is there an AJAX function that can just GET a rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

My controller is shared by links from a search result page that **needs** a layout, and from the profile page itself that does **not need** a layout. What I would like to accomplish is a single controller method `show` that is both capable of drawing the partial by AJAX from the profile page, and draw the partial and layout from the search results.

The most important restriction I have is that I can not set the `dataType:` to `script` . It **has** to be `html` . So I can't use that spiffy AJAX script call that renders the JS without the controller's format.html getting involved.

**tabs_controller.js**

```
def show
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  @tab = @organization.tabs.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :partial => 'tab', :layout => 'myHQpage' }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**javascript**

```
$.get($(this).attr('href'), null, null, "html");
```

**show.html.haml**

```
= render :partial => 'tab'
```

What AJAX function can I use here that just draws the partial, and not the entire layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand but this may help you.
Yo can add a `:layout => false` to the format.js block.

```
def show
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  @tab = @organization.tabs.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :partial => 'tab', :layout => 'myHQpage' }
    format.js { render :partial => 'tab', :layout => false }
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason that wouldn't work. Is that I'm trying to **not** use the `script` call in the ajax. So the format.html would have to be set to `false`. But that's being used by both queries. Ha, sorry if this is confusing. I've been re-editing it to make it as simple as possible :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that as unexplicable as it is, that when you set an AJAX request to script, it skips the layout param.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the 'script' dataType setting and just add a wrappertag around your search results. Then use the jQuery replaceWith function to replace the content of that tag:

```
_tag.html.erb:
<div id="search">
  ...
</div>

show.js.erb:
$('#search').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render "tab") %>');
```

Comment: Like I say above I **can not** use the `script` because when I pass script through AJAX calls on user-generated content it creates on 1 out of a 100 calls an unterminated string error. So it **has** to be HTML in the call. Otherwise, no problem. I had your answer originally :D